# Why do I need twice the same function?

Tags: c++

I am beginner in cpp language.

Recently I saw in a many classes declare twice the same function with a little different  such as:

```
    int& operator[](size_t i) {
        assert(i<size());
        return _buf[i];
    }

    const int& operator[](size_t i) const {
        assert(i<size());
        return _buf[i];
    }
```

What is the different between the function? why I need the first one? and in which cases the first function will be work and in which cases the second function will be work?

Comment: If it's cpp, why tag c?

Comment: Read this https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/562/operator-overloading/1829/array-subscript-operator#t=201705261138489740974

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On of those is `const` the other isnt. Let me put it in some context:

```
struct Foo{
    int value = 0;
    int& operator[](size_t i) {
        std::cout << "non-const\n";
        return value;
    }

    const int& operator[](size_t i) const {
        std::cout << "const\n";
        return value;
    }
};
```

The `const` version will be called on `const` instances while the non-`const` will be called on non-`const` instances. E.g.

```
int main(){
    Foo f;
    int x = f[0];
    f[0] = 3;      //  OK  
    const Foo g;
    int x = g[0];
    //g[0] = 3;      // NOT OK
```

}

...will print

```
non-const
const
```

Indeed both methods should be the same and the major difference is the `const` version returning a `const` reference while the non-`const` returns a reference that allows to modify the value.

As you correctly observed, apart from the `const`ness and the return type, the two are identical. To avoid duplicate code, sometimes it can make sense to use a small trick and write the `const` version in terms of the non-`const`:

```
const int& operator[](size_t i) const {
    std::cout << "const\n";
    return const_cast<Foo*>(this)->operator[](i);
}
```

See [here](http://ideone.com/GD32ig) for the full example.

Answer (score 1):

The first overload states that the subscript operator can modify internals of the class instance, the later states that internals of the class instance are read-only and thus, can't be modified.

Effectively, it means that `this` pointer points to either `const` or `non-const` object.

**Previously**:
You tagged your question with `C` which is not correct, as C does not offer any class member functions and thus AFAIK, `const` after the global function declaration is illegal.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you don't want to let users change your objects somehow if they are marked as *const*.

It means that if you have a class which provides *operator[]*, you don't want to let users change the internal state of objects of this class via *operator[]* if these objects are *const*.

That's why you have two overloads. If the object is *const*, then the version

```
const int& operator[](size_t i) const
```

is called. This version returns `const int&`, so you can't do any modification.

In opposite, if the object is not marked as *const*, then

```
int& operator[](size_t i)
```

is called and you are free to modify the internal state of the object via the reference returned.

Answer (score 1):

The differences are the `const` keyword:

int& operator[](size_t i) { (1)

**const** int& operator[](size_t i) **const** { (2)

The first function return a reference to the object, which means that you can modify the object (for example by doing `foo[0] = bar`.

The second use the `const` keyword twice: `const int&` means that you return a const reference that you can't modify. The second const is here to specify that this function will not modify the object.

You need those two version because (1) is used when you want to modify an element of the collection and (2) is used on const object:

you can do this:

```
void foo(std::vector<int> const& v) {
    int j = v[0];
}
```

because vector as an operator that look like (2)

Answer (score 0):

It means your class is providing the support for two things,

- Non Const Object
- Const Object

`int& operator[](size_t i)` will be called for Non const object, because there is no `const` qualifier at the end.

`const int& operator[](size_t i) const` will be called for const object, because there is `const` qualifier at the end.